# Need to switch/remove class with siblings selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, selector, siblings

I have two buttons, when I click any of one the function add the class "selected" but if I push the other button the two buttons keep the same class, I used the siblings selector but don't works correctly, ¿can you help me please?

```js
$('.btn-switch-view').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('btn-switch-view-selected');
  $('.btn-group').siblings('a.btn-switch-view-selected').removeClass('btn-switch-view-selected');
});
```

```css
.btn-group .btn-default.btn-switch-view {
  color: #b2b2b2;
}
.btn-group a.btn-default.btn-switch-view:hover,
a.btn-default.btn-switch-view-selected {
  color: #1b4298!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group">
  <a href="#" id="grid" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-switch-view">
    <i class="fa fa-th-large" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="#" id="list" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-switch-view">
    <i class="fa fa-th-list" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I just formatted your code for you but you should get into the habit of doing this yourself all of the time. It will help you and everyone else figure out what is wrong faster.

Comment: `.btn-group` has no sibling that is an anchor? It does however have two children that are anchors.

Comment: Thank you adeneo, is correct! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already have the anchor in `this`, now target the sibling anchors, and remove the class

```js
$('.btn-switch-view').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('btn-switch-view-selected')
         .siblings()
         .removeClass('btn-switch-view-selected');
});
```

```css
.btn-group .btn-default.btn-switch-view {
  color: #b2b2b2;
}
.btn-group a.btn-default.btn-switch-view:hover,
a.btn-default.btn-switch-view-selected {
  color: #1b4298!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group">
  <a href="#" id="grid" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-switch-view">
    <i class="fa fa-th-large" aria-hidden="true">Button</i>
  </a>
  <a href="#" id="list" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-switch-view">
    <i class="fa fa-th-list" aria-hidden="true">Button</i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.btn-group').siblings('a.btn-switch-view-selected')
```

is supposed to be

```
$(this).siblings('a.btn-switch-view-selected')
```

as you are trying to target siblings of `.btn-switch-view` (which is the element that is clicked) and not `.btn-group`